# angularjs local main controller var no updating with rootscope

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm trying to show errors (coming from any controller) just before my ng-view. But when the $rootScope is well update, my error var is not.

index.html

```
<div id="header" ng-controller="HeaderCtrl as head" class="header">
   <div ng-include="'views/header.html'"></div>
</div>

<div class="container" ng-controller="MainCtrl as main">
   <div ng-show="main.error" class="alert alert-danger">{{main.error}}</div>
   <div ng-view=""></div>
</div>
```

main.js

```
function MainCtrl($scope,$rootScope) {  
  var main=this;  
  main.error=$rootScope.error;  
}
```

header.js

```
function HeaderCtrl($rootScope) {
  $rootScope.error = "NO ERROR";

  function login(){  
    $rootScope.error = "ERROR";
  }
}
```

When it's not in the login function it's ok (I see well "NO ERROR" but when I call login(), I can see that $rootScope.error is well updated but not main.error ??

Comment: Why would you need to bind $rootScope.error to main.error? It's redundant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would advice you not to do what you're doing at the moment as it's really redundant to bind a `$rootScope` variable to a `$scope` variable. Just do it like this and you will have less bindings:

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="MainCtrl as main">
   <div ng-show="error" class="alert alert-danger">{{error}}</div>
   <div ng-view=""></div>
</div>  

function MainCtrl($scope) {  
  var main=this;
}
```